# Different message prompt on google colab vs Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am running the same CNN model on the same dataset (with 50000 training examples) with exactly same parameters on both Google Colab (I think it has K80 GPU) and my own system (with GTX 1080 GPU and 8700K CPU). I am using the `batch_size=32` on both but I am surprised to see that while training, Google Colab shows me;

[image]

while my own system (using PyCharm), shows me

[image]

I can understand that the difference in accuracies is may be due to different random initializations but why on Google Colab it shows the training during each epoch in terms of number of batches `1563/1563` while on my machine, it shows me in terms of number of examples in the training set i.e. `50000/50000`

In both cases I am using `tf.keras`.

Has it anything to do with the version. On my (Windows) machine, the tensorflow-gpu version is 2.1.0 whereas, on the Google Colab (probably Linux) machine, it is 2.2.0. I cannot upgrade the version on my windows machine from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0, probably they are same as can be seen here;

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please post the respective versions of what exactly you are using (stand-alone Keras or `tf.keras`).

Comment: I have updated the post!

Comment: Versions please

Comment: Did you use `.batch(BATCH_SIZE)` on your system ? It seems like it's not the case

Comment: On Google Colab the TensorFlow version is 2.2.0 whereas on my machine it is 2.1.0.